# ¿Qué quiere decir "ir de suyo"?

Tags: expresiones, locuciones, lenguaje-jurídico

Leo:

> **Va de suyo**, por lo demás, que Carles Puigdemont y Toni Comín son miembros del Parlamento Europeo desde la misma fecha en que lo es Oriol Junqueras.
>
> <sub>[¿Se derrumba la persecución del procés?](https://www.eldiario.es/contracorriente/INMUNIDAD-PARLAMENTARIA-CONCLUSIONES-ABOGADO-GENERAL_6_962813729.html), Javier Pérez Royo, eldiario.es 12 noviembre 2019</sub>

Contexto: el autor analiza las conclusiones de un abogado indicando que Junqueras tendría derecho a ser miembro del Parlamento Europeo. Dado que la casuística con Puigdemont y Comín sería equivalente, el autor nos está diciendo que ellos también tendrían dicho derecho.

Lo que me sorprende del párrafo es el uso de *va de suyo*, que es lo que he marcado al principio y nunca había visto usar así. Mirando en el DLE observo:

> [**suyo, ya**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=suyo)
>   `Del lat. suus, infl. por cuius.`
>
> **de suyo**
>   1. loc. adv. Naturalmente, propiamente o sin sugestión ni ayuda ajena.

Por lo que *va de suyo* sería algo así como *va naturalmente*. Sin embargo, el uso del verbo *ir* me hace pensar en algún tipo de locución o similar, que no conozco.

¿Es pues *ir de suyo* equivalente a *de suyo* o tiene algún matiz añadido?

Comment: This is a journalistic article. Assuming _vocabulario-técnico_ and _lenguaje-jurídico_ is an overshoot.

Comment: Or "ad hominem" or "appeal to authority". As you wish.

Comment: @23419 feel free to suggest other tags!

Comment: I agree with tag additions by 13628.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La expresión "va de suyo" es muy común en textos formales, en especial de tipo legal, y significa algo así como "es obvio", "cae de maduro", o "cae por su propio peso".

Normalmente se encuentra sólo en esa forma, con el verbo "va" (presente del indicativo, tercera persona del singular), y seguida por una proposición nominal introducida por "que" en función de sujeto pospuesto (Que xxx va de suyo -> Va que suyo que xxx).

Esta estructura permite introducir conclusiones que se consideran tan evidentes que no requieren mayor explicación.

[Aquí](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22va%20de%20suyo%20que%22) pueden encontrarse varios ejemplos.

Comment: Gracias Gustavson por la respuesta, se me olvidó aceptarla. Y muchas gracias por [tu comentario](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3241#comment6446_3241) en mi publicación anunciando mi dimisión como moderador. Me alegra que recuerdes mis palabras y qué bueno que años después sigas ofreciendo respuestas de tan alto nivel. ¡Un abrazo!

Answer (score 1):

> ***Va de suyo***

Es efectivamente una locución, una expresión característica que significa que "está de más decir", que algo es tan obvio, que no necesita justificación, porque:

> **ni falta hace decirlo**, **"cae por su propio peso"**  "**cae de** [estar] **maduro**", o va hacia abajo, *naturalmente**, por efecto del propio *peso* *suyo*)

En francés existe una expresión similar:

> *[Aller de soi](https://context.reverso.net/traduccion/frances-espanol/aller+de+soi)* (ça va de soi, [va por sí mismo, no hace falta decir nada más])

---

Por lo tanto, en cuanto a tu duda, sí tiene un matiz distinto respecto a la forma que refieres

> **De suyo**

que es una frase para decir "**en sí mismo**"

> Asimismo, un régimen democrático exige ***de suyo*** tanto la participación ciudadana como la discusión y la crítica públicas.